# How to get Facebook Post Like, Comment and Share action from user

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I stumbled into a facebook post where when user click the like button, or share the post or post a comment, a facebook page bot will automatically message the user. Here is the exact post:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ninjateam.org/posts/1799394500352455
```

I'm trying to look into the facebook developers API documentation on how to do those kind of functionality but always failed. Can you point me to the correct path where to start or what resource is used in those kind or post?

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: Pages can reply privately to a comment, I guess that’s the feature you mean. Just because they liked or shared however, is not a situation in which you can message them.